# phpMyAdmin config not working on Centos 6.5

Tags: phpmyadmin

Recently installed phpMyAdmin using yum:

```
yum install phpmyadmin
```

phpmyadmin was installed to

```
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

but there is no config file there.

there is a config.inc.php file at

```
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

as the phpMyAdmin docs indicate (http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linux-distributions - read bit about Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

However, changes to that file are not picked up by the phpMyAdmin application. I've tried putting a copy of that in various locations:

```
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config/config.inc.php
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config/config.inc.php
```

without success. None of these files are used as config, and they all had the correct permissions (a+rwx), as did their parent directories.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? Naming the file `config.inc.php` is correct, right?

Comment: Did you restart your Apache server? Is `apache.conf` file is exist in `/etc/phpMyAdmin/`? Is the line `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` exist in `apache2/apache2.conf` file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I restarted Apache. The application's config file lives at /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf (Apache is configured to pick up the file on restart). I can access the application ok (which should mean it's not an Apache issue, right?)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out in the end? Run into the same issue just now...

Answer (score 7):

phpMyAdmin can't read config file and using default config.

I've solved this issue by setting chmod 644 to this file:

> /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

And chmod 755 to this folder:

> /etc/phpMyAdmin/

Check file and folder directories are readable by user that you're running web server also.

Good luck.

Comment: And check your mbstring settings, in my case phpmyadmin was not work until I set in apache conf this: `php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when running nginx web server on CentOS 7. I figured out that the problem lies in insufficient access permissions to the configuration file, which resides in /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.

By default this file and parent folder is owned by root:apache and changing group to nginx solves this issue.

```
chown -R root:nginx /etc/phpMyAdmin/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. I know it's al old thread but Google brought me here, so I'll give the solution to what was my problem.

I had declared the basedir in PHP as `/etc/phpmyadmin` like that in lowercase but it should be `/etc/phpMyAdmin` in camelcase. An absurd mistake that took me 1 hour to figure out.

If you want to quickly see how it looks in your configuration just run

```
echo ini_get('open_basedir');
```

Check if the names are correct if not then change in php.ini or any other configurations you use in your case for PHP.