# Unable to autologin in phpmyadmin on my dev machine

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've mysql and phpmyadmin in my development virtual machine.

It's all working. I can access to phpmyadmin using root user and the root password.

I am trying to autologin.

So I copied `config.sample.inc.php` as `config.inc.php` then entered the credentials and changed the auth mode

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']='root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='MyCorrectRootPassword';

$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
```

When I open my browser pointing a phpmyadmin, I always see the login page, and without errors at all.

Is there any missing settings I must do ?

I followed documentation @ https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#generic-settings

I read this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/phpmyadmin-ignores-config-inc-php

so I checked file permissions: it' `644` owned by `root:root` (like all other files in the phpmyadmin folder).

> Note: phpmyadmin it's installed at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.
> It's v4.9.7 installed on a Debian 10.4 using distribution package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO question helped me: [phpMyAdmin config not working on Centos 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135239/phpmyadmin-config-not-working-on-centos-6-5)

I discovered `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php'

It ends with

```
/* Support additional configurations */
foreach (glob('/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/*.php') as $filename)
{
    include($filename);
}
```

So I created `/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/autologin.conf.php`

```
<?php

/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][1]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][1]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][1]['user']='root';
$cfg['Servers'][1]['password']='MyCorrectRootPassword';
```

And it worked

Comment: Even though this answer specifically addresses CentOS, the packages are built the same way for Debian/Ubuntu so the answer is also correct. The packaged versions put their own `config.inc.php` file in `/etc/phpmyadmin/` and you can edit that directly or put your changes in the `/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/` directory as realtebo has done, as that is parsed after the main config.inc.php. (The exception would be if you have more than one server defined, you would have to reference them by array number rather than $i, but would be pretty advanced usage at that point).

Comment: Oh, you are the asker as well as answerer, I didn't notice that at first. Glad you solved it. Editing config.inc.php directly would mean you have changes that you'd need to reconcile when installing an update, that is the advantage of putting the changes in the conf.d file as you have done (since those changes are not changed on upgrade). Cheers.